# NoSuchElementException occurs even though the element is present - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

While working with Selenium in Python, even after the wait for many seconds, `NoSuchElementException` occurs. I am selecting the element by using `XPATH` but the script is not fetching the element. I have tried using **Implicit Wait** as well as **Explicit Wait** but no progress. And yes, sometimes it works too. I don't know why.

---

Possible **XPATHs** I have tried:

```
//*[@id="mount_0_0_Xh"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]
//*[@id="mount_0_0_Xh"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a
//*[@id="mount_0_0_Xh"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div[1]/div[2]
```

---

**Python Code**

```
row = 1
col = 1
post = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_pf"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[{r}]/div[{c}]'.format(r = str(row), c = str(col)))
post.click()
```

&

```
row = 1
col = 1
post = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_pf"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[{r}]/div[{c}]/a'.format(r = str(row), c = str(col)))
post.click()
```

&

```
row = 1
col = 1
post = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_pf"]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[{r}]/div[{c}]/a/div[1]/div[2]'.format(r = str(row), c = str(col)))
post.click()
```

Comment: Check if the elements are in an iframe or shadowroot.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan No, they are not.

Comment: Share the website link here, if it is ok to do so.

Comment: Could you please provide page url or page html

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the question that this code works sometimes. When I tried to figure out the issue, I get to know that every time I am reloading that particular page, somehow the value of id `//*[@id="mount_0_0_Xh"]` was changing continuously. So the solution is:

> Instead of copying the **XPATH** of an element from a webpage, try to copy **Full XPATH**. This worked for me.